# Powershell: Add line break on start

Tags: powershell, line, new-operator

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: take a look at the `prompt` idea >>> about Prompts - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.1 <<< ///// there are several modules of making highly customized prompts over at the PSGallery.

Comment: Great, this looks very useful! @Lee_Dailey

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

At:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Documents\PowerShell
```

There should be a file named:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

With the next content:

```
function prompt {
    # Your non-prompt logic here
    #$prompt = Write-Prompt "Text before posh-git prompt " -ForegroundColor ([ConsoleColor]::Green)
    $prompt += & $GitPromptScriptBlock
    $prompt += "`n"
    #$prompt += Write-Prompt "Text after posh-git prompt" -ForegroundColor ([ConsoleColor]::Magenta)
    if ($prompt) { "$prompt " } else { " " }
}
```

And that's it!